# Will I be Charged for a VM instance which was running in a project I shut down?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have recently shut down a project and I had a VM instance running in that. Will that charge my free trial credit even after shut down??
If yes, will it charge even after deletion(after 30 days of shut down)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing will be terminated once the resources are deleted.

This should be roughly coincident with your request to delete the project that contains the resources but there could be slight latency..

Deleting a project deletes the project's resources. It's a blunt but effective way to terminate all a project's resources in a single transaction.